# How to add dynamic attributes to dynamic model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a Dynamic Model and its attributes in Ruby on Rails.

Model names and respective model attributes are fetched from the database

Model names:

```
model_names(id, name)
Eg: model_names(1, "Customer")
```

Model attributes:

```
    model_attributes(id, model_name_id,attr_id, attr_name, attr_type, attr_nullable, attr_default_value,attr_key)
Eg: model_attributes(1, 1, "CustomerID", "Customer Id", "int(11)", FALSE, "PRI", NULL)
    model_attributes(1, 1, "Name", "Name", "varchar(40)", FALSE, NULL, NULL)
```

I am able to create Dynamic Model using below

```
    Object.const_set("Customer", Class.new(ApplicationRecord))
```

Now I want to create the columns for the Model. How can I create it dynamically without creating a table?

Comment: Do you absolutely need those models to be subclasses of ActiveRecord?

Comment: ActiveRecord is initialised on RoR boot and it infers all the data from the database connection. RoR has this philosophy of "convention over configuration" which is very helpful when you try to bootstrap the project, but will become pain in the ass if you'll try to do something idiosyncratic, like what you're doing here. Even if there's low level AR API suitable for your use case I'd expect lot's of troubles down that road.

Comment: On the other hand it's relatively easy to build PORO or even ActiveModel objects with your approach. And have some kind repository pattern to deal with DB.

Comment: If your idea doesn't have any hidden motives, I think `OpenStruct` can help enough: `Object.const_set("Customer", Class.new(OpenStruct)`

Comment: @DannyOcean Yes I definitely need these models to be subclass of ActiveRecord and my goal is to create queries using that with help of Modle_name.arel_table. Let me know how to add the dynamic attributes to the model

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I don't find option to specify my attributes types,etc in OpenStruct

Comment: @Galet Can you add expected behaviour, I mean how you want to add this types?

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I want to add all columns mentioned in model_attributes OR at least name, type, default, key,nullable